# Deixar datas em ordem automaticamente

Tags: microsoft-excel, tabela-html

Como eu faço pra deixar minha tabela que tem datas organizada em ordem, tipo, tem as celulas: data de emissão; nome; data de vencimento; situaçao, queria que minha tabela se organizasse por data d vencimento automaticamente quando eu colocasse um novo valor, seja clicando em um botão ou quando eu a abro. Creio q devo usar vba, só que não entendo nada do msm.

Dsd já agradeço quem poder ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ordenar automaticamente usando VBA**

Para implementar a solução, é necessário que a guia `Desenvolvedor` esteja habilitada. Caso você não tenha feito isso ainda, veja como fazer em [Mostrar a guia Desenvolvedor](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/Mostrar-a-guia-Desenvolvedor-e1192344-5e56-4d45-931b-e5fd9bea2d45).

Tomando como exemplo a seguinte tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Execute os seguintes passos para automatizar a ordenação pela coluna data:

**1) Criar macro de ordenação da tabela**

1.1) Clique na guia `Desenvolvedor`

1.2) Clique no botão Visual Basic (ou pressione `Alt`+`F11`) para abrir a janela VBA

1.3) No menu `Inserir`, clique na opção `Módulo` para adicionar o `Modulo1` ao VBAProject

1.4) Na janela de código do `Modulo1`, adicione o seguinte procedimento:

```
Public Sub OrdernarPlanilha1()

    Const INI_COL_ORDENAR = "Plan1!B1" 

    Range(INI_COL_ORDENAR).Sort Key1:=Range(INI_COL_ORDENAR), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, _
            MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

- Este procedimento vai ordenar toda a tabela em volta da célula especificada na constante `INI_COL_ORDENAR`.
- A constante `INI_COL_ORDENAR` deve conter o endereço da célula onde inicia a coluna que contém os valores da ordenação (no nosso exemplo, é a célula `Plan1!B1`)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2) Chamar macro de ordenação quando abrir o arquivo da planilha**

2.1) Na janela de código do módulo `EstaPasta_de_trabalho`, adicione o seguinte procedimento:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    OrdernarPlanilha1
End Sub
```

- Este procedimento executa a ordenação automaticamente quando o arquivo é aberto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**3) Adicionar um botão para chamar a macro de ordenação**

3.1) Volte para a janela do Excel e clique na guia `Desenvolvedor`

3.2) Clique no botão `Inserir Controles` e selecione o controle `Botão`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3.3) Desenhe o botão na planilha, selecione a macro `OrdernarPlanilha1` e clique `OK`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3.4) Altere o rótulo do botão para "Ordenar"

**4) Chamar a macro de ordenação quando a planilha for alterada**

Particularmente, eu não gosto desse procedimento porque ele muda a ordem das linhas enquanto você edita a tabela e isso pode causar alguma confusão. Mas se desejar implementar, basta fazer o seguinte:

4.1) Na janela VBA, adicione o seguinte código ao módulo da planilha (no caso do nosso exemplo será o módulo `Plan1`)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    OrdernarPlanilha1
End Sub
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pronto, é só usar!

**Mais de uma tabela na mesma planilha...**

Se a planilha tiver mais de uma tabela a ser ordenada, a rotina de ordenação pode ser alterada conforme a sugestão abaixo para ser executada para cada uma das tabelas:

```
Public Sub OrdernarPlanilha1()
    OrdernarTabela "Plan1!B1"
    OrdernarTabela "Plan1!B10"
End Sub   

Private Sub OrdernarTabela(ini_col_ordenar As String)

    Range(ini_col_ordenar).Sort Key1:=Range(ini_col_ordenar), _
        Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, _
            MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom
End Sub
```

Comment: Cara. muito obrigado, isso já faz me ajudou muito, porem na planilha tem varias tabelas, separada e todas elas precisam ser organizadas por data, tem 4 contas por exemplo na mesma planilha, cada conta tem nome, data, valor etc, aí queria q cada uma delas se ajustasse, desse jeito q o sr me respondeu ela ajusta toda a planilha em função de uma mesma coluna, são tabelas diferentes numa mesma planilha, se tiver como eu agradeço muito

Comment: Como faço pra ela se organizar a partir d uma coluna específica, quando coloco por exemplo D4 na variável la, ela continua organizando toda a tabela, e outra coisa, na tabela, tem uma coluna que não pode mudar, cada tabela tem 9 colunas, porem a coluna 9 n pode sair da ordem, como faço isso? Desde já agradeço

Comment: Adicionei uma solução ao final da resposta para resolver o problema de várias tabelas na mesma planilha.

Comment: Não consigo vislumbrar uma forma simples para ordenar a partir de uma coluna específica, ou para não alterar uma coluna. Para fazer isso, você vai precisar especificar o intervalo de cada tabela na função `sort`. Por exemplo `Range("A1:C5").Sort Key1:=Range("B1")...`

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado, resolveu aqui